# Why is my CollectionAssert in my Unit Test always failing in my .NET Application?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, unit-testing

I'm writing a unit test which needs to check if two arrays of object match each other.  I've tried a few different approaches but all of them fail.  The most obvious approach was the `CollectionAssert` which, according to what I have read, doesn't care about the source only the values and order of the data itself, despite the two array of objects matching each other, the test still fails and I'm lost as to why.

Let's take my unit test

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetMyData_ShouldReturnDataDto_WhenAllIsOk()
{
    // Arrange
    var userId = "123-456";

    Shared.Car customer = new()
        {
            Id = userId,
            OwnerProfile = new Shared.OwnerProfile
            {
                Title = "Mr",
                FirstName = "Bob",
                Surname = "Smith",
                CarsOwned = new Shared.CarsOwned[]
                {
                    new CarsOwned { 
                        Make = "Ford", 
                        Model = "Mustang",
                        Rental = false 
                    },
                    new CarsOwned { 
                        Make = "Ford", 
                        Model = "Fiesta",
                        Rental = true 
                    }
                }                    
            }
        };    
    customerRepo.GetCustomerById(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(customer);

    // Act
    var data = await sut.GetCustomerProfile(userId);

    // Assert
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(customer.OwnerProfile.CarsOwned, data.CarsOwned);
}
```

When I set a break point in my test to debug it, I can clearly see that both instances of `CarsOwned` in the `CollectionAssert` have identidcal data in the identical order although the sources are different.

Is the `CollectionAssert` the most appropriate for this setup?  I believed it was based on the documentation and the described behaviour.

When I run the test I recieve the error of:

> CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)

This suggest to me that it's not happy that it's comparing the two arrays from different sources but I could be wrong about that.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I use FluentAssertions, which has a function 'BeEquivalentTo' which does a property by property comparison, rather than an object comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you did not override the `Equals()` method in the CarsOwned class. I assume that it is this method which is used by `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`.

By default, the `Equals()` method return true only if the both parameters have the same reference (~the memory address). It means that in your mind both objects are equals, but for the computer they are completely different objects. So you have to tell to the program how to compare two instance of the same class.

I let you search how implement a correct and efficient Equals() method, but this is not very complicate (because you do not have a lot of field and there is not some complex business logic).

See you, Dylan